# PHP5 tier based authorization script?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, scripting, login-script

Are there any PHP login scripts around that I can learn from?

I want to have a control panel that shows different options to different users depending on level of privilege.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are thousands of PHP scripts around that you can read and learn from.

You are welcome to download the framework [MCRwebapp](http://code.google.com/p/mcrwebapp/downloads/list)  from Google Code and read the AbstractApp class to see both authentication (user password) and authorization (user permissions).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try it out. Great to see people showing off their work. (BTW, I assume that you are willing to support it on some level if your suggesting it...)

Comment: I downloaded it ans couldn't extract it in Ubuntu 9.04... Can you get it to me as a zip? moshefromsinai@gmail.com

Comment: Use this command on Ubuntu or any Linux: tar jxvf webapp.tar.bz

Answer (score 2):

"Login" implies authentication. "Levels of privilege" implies authorization. Although they seem similar and are often discussed together as "auth", they are quite different. "Authn" is global and simply takes in a username and password, or auth token, etc. "Authz" must be implemented at an object level and is more complicated; consider using a framework that supports it natively.

Comment: Not in particular. Google finds Symfony, Yii, Lion, and more.